using scanf to read strings in nasm
im working on a script which will read a string from the user and print it back, i wanted the script to read the input using scanf and print it back with printf.
So far i tried following those forums:

https://www.reddit.com/r/asm/comments/gdirzw/segfault_when_using_scanf_in_x86_assembly_nasm/ (we both have similar problems but my version uses strings instead of integers)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1wXEyOUGJE ( This was my closest attempt where the code was executed without any error but it would give a seg error on runtime.)


    ; Read a string from input using scanf
    mov rdi, msg1 
    mov rsi, string_format          
    mov al, 0
    call sscanf


How to use scanf in NASM? ( the code does not work with my string)

i also tried pushing the variables to the stack instead of using cpu registries
and in a useless attempt i also tried to add [] surrounding the variables. none of those worked for my string.
The code im using right now (the closest thing i could get) is this

SECTION .data
     endLine db 0Ah, 0
     integer_printf:     db  '%d',   10,0
     float_printf        db  '%f',   10,0
     string_format       db  '%s',   10,0
SECTION .bss
     msg1     resb 33
SECTION .text
     extern printf, strcat, strcpy, malloc, scanf
     global main
printInt:
     mov rdi,integer_printf
     xor rax,rax
     call printf
     ret
printFloat:
     mov rdi,float_printf
     call printf
     ret
printStr:
     mov rdi,string_format
     xor rax,rax
     call printf
     ret
exit_program:
     mov rax, 60
     syscall
strlen:
     push    rbx
     mov     rbx, rax
nextchar:
     cmp     byte [rax], 0
     jz      finished
     inc     rax
     jmp     nextchar
finished:
     sub     rax, rbx
     pop     rbx
     ret
main:
     lea rdi, [msg1]
     mov byte [rdi + 0], 'h'
     mov byte [rdi + 1], 'e'
     mov byte [rdi + 2], 'l'
     mov byte [rdi + 3], 'l'
     mov byte [rdi + 4], 'o'
     mov byte [rdi + 5], ','
     mov byte [rdi + 6], ' '
     mov byte [rdi + 7], 'i'
     mov byte [rdi + 8], 'n'
     mov byte [rdi + 9], 's'
     mov byte [rdi + 10], 'e'
     mov byte [rdi + 11], 'r'
     mov byte [rdi + 12], 't'
     mov byte [rdi + 13], ' '
     mov byte [rdi + 14], 'y'
     mov byte [rdi + 15], 'o'
     mov byte [rdi + 16], 'u'
     mov byte [rdi + 17], 'r'
     mov byte [rdi + 18], ' '
     mov byte [rdi + 19], 'n'
     mov byte [rdi + 20], 'a'
     mov byte [rdi + 21], 'm'
     mov byte [rdi + 22], 'e'
     mov byte [rdi + 23], '.'
     mov byte [rdi + 24], ' '
     mov byte [rdi + 25], 0
     mov rax, msg1
     call strlen
     mov rdi, rax
     call malloc
     mov rdi, rax
     mov rsi, msg1
     call strcpy
     mov [msg1], rax

     mov rsi, [msg1]
     call printStr

     mov rsi, msg1 
     mov rdi, string_format          
     mov al, 0
     call scanf

     mov rsi, [msg1]
     call printStr

     MOV rdi, 0
     call exit_program


error:
hello, insert your name.
Seg error created (core dump)
i would guess my msg1 buff is not a string? or its not a c string? im not sure what i got wrong
Thanks for any help in advice

You used sscanf not scanf. Also you got the operands reversed. Furthermore your msg1 is initially a zero length string, no point running strlen on it, even less point allocating zero bytes of memory (off by one error) and copying it there. Finally setting msg1 to a pointer which it is not. Anyway if your question is about the scanf then remove the initial unrelated code.

@Jester sorry, this is not the full code. i cutted the useless part, i will edit the question showing the complete code

It's a bad idea to use msg1 as a pointer. Not sure what you want with the copying but you can fix the crash by using mov rsi, msg1 instead of mov rsi, [msg1]. The error is not with the scanf. PS: you should always limit the size when reading into a buffer to avoid overflow. Also consider learning to use a debugger.

@Jester mhhh the code is alredy like that in the snippet i provided in the original message and the error is the same. i will try to see if i can get something using a debugger

The posted code works if you change what I said. Also you don't need the line feed in the string_format.

@Jester if i changed each mov rsi, [msg1] to mov rsi, msg1 it will print this:
�"�
Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)
if you ment to change only the mov rsi, msg1 before the call for scanf then that gives the same output, maybe im doing something wrong
     mov rsi, [msg1]
     call printStr

     mov rsi, msg1 
     call scanf

     mov rsi, [msg1]
     call printStr

     MOV rdi, 0
     call exit_program


No the scanf is fine. You only need to change the last mov rsi, [msg] that is before the final printStr.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here's how to read an input line using scanf and print it with printf:
https://godbolt.org/z/de6PWarTe
Looks like you also want to print a prompt. You can add this in front of the scanf:
printf("Hello insert your name: "); fflush(stdout);

Then look at the resulting assem lang to see how to do it.
And by the way, scanf() can be difficult to use, especially if you want to validate user input. The man page itself says:

It is very difficult to use these functions correctly, and it is preferable to read entire lines with fgets(3) or getline(3) and parse them later with sscanf(3) or more specialized functions such as strtol(3). ... These functions make it difficult to distinguish newlines from other white space, This is especially problematic with line-buffered input, like the standard input stream. These functions can't report errors after the last non-suppressed conversion specification.

Like the man page says, you should use fgets() and sscanf() instead of just plain scanf().
I think you should spend some time using https://godbolt.org since it should be a very valuable resource as you continue to learn nasm.

Thanks, i will try with fgets and sscanf, (i alredy tried sscanf with no results)

You need to understand what each of the functions do. If you read the man pages, you'll see that scanf() reads data from standard in and parses it. Whereas sscanf() parses data that you pass it in a string buffer. Your call to sscanf() didn't work because you didn't read anything into a buffer first. That's what the fgets() is for.
